# Android - textview doesn't show up

Tags: android, xml, layout

[image]

For some reason, my textview `Add a base` doesn't show up when I launch the app on my phone. I have no idea why, 'cause it is displayed on Android studio :O

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace `tools:text="@string/add_base"` with `android:text="@string/add_base"`

Attributes in the `tools` namespace are shown only when designing layouts. When you build your app, the build tools remove these attributes so there is no effect on your APK size or runtime behavior.

Reference: https://developer.android.com/studio/write/tool-attributes

Comment: Thank you, I don't know what this "tool" is doing here, i didn't put it intentionally

Answer (score 1):

**tools:text="YOUR TEXT"** can be used for your design and preview purpose.
If you add any text as a **tools:text** app will not use this text as that is not the actual text that should be rendered on the app

So instead of this, you should use **android:text="YOUR TEXT"**